# Modify entries in configuration file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

We have the following configuration file

```
more /tmp/file

delete.topic.enable=true
broker.id=-1
advertised.listeners=null
.
.
.
```

We need to convert all syntax above as the following:

1. Change the characters until “=” separator  to uppercase characters
2. Add `KAFKA_` in the beginning of each line
3. Replaces each dot “.” To under line  “_” until the “=” separator

Example of expected results

```
KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE=true
KAFKA_BROKER_ID=-1
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=null
.
.
.
```

Any sed suggestion for this changing ?

We try this ,

but this also convert the charterers after the “=” separator ( not as should be ) , and also we not sure how we can add the `KAFKA_` in the beginning

```
sed 's/[a-z]/\U&/g'  /tmp/file | sed s'/\./_/g'

DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE=TRUE
BROKER_ID=-1
ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=NULL
.
.
```

Comment: Since you said `Replaces each dot “.” To under line “_” until the “=” separator` you should include a case where there are `.`s after the `=` in your sample input/output for us to test against as it'd be easy to assume a simple `s/\./_/g` would suffice and if that was tested with your current sample input/output we wouldn't know that it failed the `until the “=” separator` part of your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU awk for the 3rd arg to match():

```
$ awk 'match($0,/([^=]+)(.*)/,a){ gsub(/\./,"_",a[1]); print "KAFKA_" toupper(a[1]) a[2]}' file
KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE=true
KAFKA_BROKER_ID=-1
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=null
```

With any awk:

```
$ awk 'match($0,/[^=]+/){ tag=substr($0,1,RLENGTH); gsub(/\./,"_",tag); print "KAFKA_" toupper(tag) substr($0,1+RLENGTH)}' file
KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE=true
KAFKA_BROKER_ID=-1
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F "=" 'OFS="="{gsub(/\./,"_",$1);print "KAFKA_"toupper($1)"="$2}' FILE
```

OUTPUT

```
KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE=true
KAFKA_BROKER_ID=-1
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=nul1
```

python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import re
k=open('file1','r')
for i in k:
    y=i.split('=')
    z=y[0].upper().replace(".","_")+"="+y[1]
    print "KAFKA_{0}".format(z).strip()
```

output

```
KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE=true
KAFKA_BROKER_ID=-1
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=null
```

Answer (score 0):

`perl` one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/^([^=]+)/KAFKA_\U$1/; s/\.(?=[^=]*=)/_/g' file
```